# Dockerfile CMD not accepting variables for substitution

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Unable to use variables on the CMD line:

```
#CMD ["/opt/jdk/bin/java", "-jar", "${ARTIFACTID}-${VERSION}.${PACKAGING}"]
CMD ["/opt/jdk/bin/java", "-jar", "ssltools-domain-LATEST.jar"]
```

Latest line works, not the first.

Any help or workaround very appreciated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you write the arguments to `CMD` (or `ENTRYPOINT`) as a JSON string, as in...

```
CMD ["/opt/jdk/bin/java", "-jar", "ssltools-domain-LATEST.jar"]
```

...the command is executed directly with the `exec` system call and is *not processed by a shell*.  That means no i/o redirection, no wildcard processing...and no variable expansion.  You can fix this in a number of ways:

- You can just write it as a plain string instead, as in:

  ```
    CMD /opt/jdk/bin/java -jar ${ARTIFACTID}-${VERSION}.${PACKAGING}
  ```

  When the argument is not a JSON construct, it gets passed to `sh -c`.
- You can do as suggested by Philip, and pass the arguments to `sh -c` yourself:

  ```
    CMD ["sh", "-c", "/opt/jdk/bin/java -jar ${ARTIFACTID}-${VERSION}.${PACKAGING}"]
  ```

  Those two options are basically equivalent.
- A third option is to put everything into a shell script, and then run that:

  ```
    COPY start.sh /start.sh
    CMD ["sh", "/start.sh"]
  ```

  This is especially useful if you need to perform more than a simple command line.

Comment: Excellent, I also found the variables you pass to the shell have to be ENV not ARG. Thanks for the shell script tip. it will be the cleanest adding all parameters into one script and run it.
`ARG PACKAGING=jar
ENV PACKAGING=${PACKAGING}
`

Answer (score 2):

Try [this little trick](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5509#issuecomment-45243772) first:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/opt/jdk/bin/java -jar ${ARTIFACTID}-${VERSION}.${PACKAGING}"]
```